# I have selected data from SQL server using VBscript

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, c#-4.0, vbscript

I'm trying to get data from database using vb script.I have the code as below:

```
<FORM action="" method="post">
        <!--#include file="open_conn.asp" -->
    <% 
        'Get id dynamique from id unsubcribe mail
        id = Request.QueryString("ID_unsub")
        'Selection phone number
        SQL = "SELECT  telephone FROM  KS_enfants WHERE IDenfant=1"
        Set Retel = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
        Server.ScriptTimeout=120
        Retel.Open SQL,session("mycon"),1,1
        '======================= Read data and sent=================
        Do While NOT Retel.Eof
        tel = Retel("telephone") 

        Loop
    %>

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="padding:0; background:#fff;">
                    <tr>
                       <td colspan="2" style="height:auto;">
                        <input type="text" name="txt_num"  id="txt_num" style="width:250px;" value="<%  tel %>" />
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>
```

In fact, I got the error messages:

```
 Erreur d'exécution Microsoft VBScript erreur '800a000d'

Type incompatible: 'tel'

/Emailing/template_email/emailing-apprenant/righ-side-1.asp, ligne 90
```

I do not know how to fix it.Anyone know, help me please, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think instead of:

```
<%  tel %>
```

You meant:

```
<%=tel %>
```

Or

```
<% Response.Write(tel) %>
```